# Why codeblocks asking me to add a ";" after else's condition? If I add a ":", there is still a logic error.(check the quesetion body for more detail)

Tags: c++

Write a C++ program to check whether a given integer is positive even, negative even, positive odd or negative odd.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cout<< "Enter the number you want to check: \n";
    cin>>n;

    if(n>0 &&n%2 ==0){
        cout<< "number is positive even \n";
    }
    else if(n<0 &&n%2 ==0){
        cout<< "number is negative even \n";
    }
    else if(n<0 &&n%2 !=0){
        cout<< "number is negative odd \n";
    }
    else (n>0 && n%2 !=0){
            cout<< "number is positive odd \n";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

This is my code. When I don't add a semicolon after `else (n>0 && n%2 !=0)`. It shows an error: expected ';' before '{' token.
When there is semi colon there is a logic error where else output is shown no matter what the number is.

Comment: There shouldn't be a condition for the final `else` branch of an `if..else if..else` construct. Should that just be `else if` as well?

Comment: It should be `else if` and not just `else`. (or you should remove the condition next to it if it really was intended as `else`.)

Comment: @CherryDT `else if` will more accurately match the printed text. After all `0` is neither positive nor odd.

Comment: In cases like these, where the final else condition is actually implicit, because all other cases are covered, but I want to add the condition for clarity, I put it in an inline comment `/* condition */`.

Answer (score 6):

You can not write `else (condition)` without using `if`.
the correct way is write `else if (condition)` like you are doing or you can simply write `else { cout << "Number is positive"; }`.

Comment: sorry, couldn't understand. I have used if  condition. what are you trying to tell me.I just started to learn C++ last to last week ago. please explain a little more

Comment: I'd say that the answer as it currently exists is very clear. Looking at the history of the answer, I feel confident that the answer was clear enough when you commented. It's cool that you're starting out learning C++, but there is no extra clarification needed here.

Answer (score 1):

You can't leave out the `if` when you have a condition - the compiler interprets `n>0 && n%2 !=0` as the body of the `else` branch, equivalent to this:

```
else { 
    (n>0 && n%2 !=0)
}
{
        cout<< "number is positive odd \n";
}
```

which *is* missing a semicolon - and if you add one, you get an expression that does nothing and an unconditional output, equivalent to:

```
else 
    n>0 && n%2 !=0;
cout<< "number is positive odd \n";
```

Since none of your conditions cover the case where `n` is zero, you probably want

```
else if (n>0 && n%2 !=0){
    cout<< "number is positive odd \n";
}
else {
    cout << "number is zero\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line: `else (n>0 && n%2 !=0)`

`else` means that if all the above `if` and `if-else` conditions are false, then the logic in the `else` condition is executed, no condition need. But you add a condition
`n>0 && n%2 !=0` which is wrong syntax.

You can fix it by changing:

```cpp
else (n>0 && n%2 !=0){
    cout<< "number is positive odd \n";
}
```

To:

```cpp
else if (n>0 && n%2 !=0){
    cout<< "number is positive odd \n";
}
```

Or:

```cpp
else{
    cout<< "number is positive odd \n";
}
```